# need to use case when for select document path for two type?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

HOW TO WRITE QUERY

```
SELECT DOC_PATH,
(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE=1 THEN SCAN_PATH from documents where DOC_NO='A112' AND ROWNUM=1 END) AS DOCS,
(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE=2 THEN SCAN_PATH from documents where DOC_NO='B331' AND ROWNUM=1 END) AS DOCS
FROM documents
```

Comment: Add sample data please.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your query implies that you should be doing an aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    DOC_PATH,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 1 AND DOC_NO = 'A112' THEN SCAN_PATH END) AS DOCS1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN DOCTYPE = 2 AND DOC_NO = 'B331' THEN SCAN_PATH END) AS DOCS2
FROM documents
GROUP BY DOC_PATH;
```

Comment: its getting all documents path need one path for A112

Comment: That's probably because you're missing the WHERE clause.

Comment: @Littlefoot please explain where to add WHERE clause need to get DocPath against app_no

Comment: Between FROM and GROUP BY.